# jQuery scroll to ID from different page in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

What I want is,consider this case, I am on a page `home`, when i click `services`, it goes to another page named `services`. on this page there is an element named `here`, i want to scroll to that view when i click on services.

I cannot find any tutorial or anything, please link a tutorial or anything that might help.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: @SupunPraneeth consider this case, I am on a page `home`, when i click `services`, it goes to another page. on this page there is an element named `here`, i want to scroll to that view when i click on `services`.

Comment: here is static element  or `elementID` is the id of that element ?

Comment: that is irrelevant.

Comment: you can put `id` in `here` element  and using jquery scroll you can scroll to that element, have you tried this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you wanna use an ID anchor to do this...
You can pass a `window.location.hash = 'target'` in some place in your website or just add in your URL.

or use directly in your url:
`www.yourwebsite.com#target`

```
<div id="target">...</div>
```

using the Jquery you can trigger when the page is loaded like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var targeOffsetTop = $('[role="target"]').offset().top;
  $( document ).scrollTop(targeOffsetTop)();
});
```

And if you wanna something more smooth, just using this way:

```
var targeOffsetTop $('[role="target"]').offset().top
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(targeOffsetTop).offset().top,
});
```

Refer: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/#scrollTop2 (He use an anchor to go to the section of page)

Comment: it gives an error at ` var targeOffsetTop $('[role="target"]').offset().top` error is `uncaught syntax error:unexpected identifier`

Comment: @AkAk, the `var targetOffsetTop` receive a value, I fixed it add `=`, please try again

Answer (score 0):

Youn can use the following code: https://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/#